# SSRS ReportingService2010 SOAP Call returning HTML, not SOAP XML

Tags: go, soap, reporting-services

I'm trying to make a SOAP call to the SSRSReporting SOAP service, and receive a SOAP response in XML format. I am trying to use [go-wsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl) to generate a SSRS SOAP API, however it seems that its "not working" in Go. I want to list the children using go-wsdl. The code below is returning an empty response.

```
package main

import ssrs "ssrs/myservice"
import "fmt"

//curl  http://172.16.1.249/ReportServer/ListChildren -n -v --ntlm -u viewpointops\\dustinf.7C49
func main() {
    fmt.Print("gucci\n")
    client := ssrs.NewSOAPClient("http://$HOST/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx", true, &ssrs.BasicAuth{Login: "$USER", Password: "$PASSWORD"})
    resp := ssrs.ListChildrenResponse{}

    err := client.Call("ListChildren", ssrs.ListChildren{ ItemPath: "/VCS/Custom/", Recursive: true }, resp) 
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println("%v", resp)
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe I don't understand SOAP and what it is, but also know that when I try to duplicate the request in curl, its not returning the XML response I expect it to return.

```
curl http://$HOST/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx -n -v --ntlm -u $USER  -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAaction: ListChildren" --data '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlg/soap/envelope/"><Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><ListChildren xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer"><ItemPath>/VCS/Custom/</ItemPath><Recursive>true</Recursive></ListChildren></Body></Envelope>' -H "Accept: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "User-Agent: PHP/SOAP"
```

I receive this response:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.6251.0">
    <title>172.16.1.249/ReportServer - /</title>
  </head>
  <body><H1>172.16.1.249/ReportServer - /</H1><hr>

<pre>   Thursday, December 12, 2013 4:04 PM        &lt;dir&gt; <A HREF="?%2fVCS&amp;rs:Command=ListChildren">VCS</A>
</pre><hr>
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 11.0.6251.0

  </body>
 </html>
```

I'd REALLY like to have the response returned in SOAP XML format so I can use a SOAP parser. I tried the Accept Header, but that's not working. I am mostly asking SO because I don't know what else to try.  If not, I guess I can just parse the HTML version, but the whole point is to use the generated code from wsdl and use the SOAP interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting `SOAPAction` header while calling `ListChildren`?

Comment: 1) The required value for the content type may be `application/xml` or `text/xml+soap` or `application/xml+soap`; 2) Try setting the `Accept` header field to `text/xml` or `application/xml` or `text/xml+soap` or `application/xml+soap`.

Comment: In general, I'd try to capture the traffic of some "official" client making a *proper* request to that service and then try to figure out what made that possible. Look for Wireshark and `tcpdump`. (Note that this won't work with HTTPS—unless you possess the server's private key).

Comment: BTW the XML namespace in your cURL example has an error: it has to be "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/". And so another shot in the dark. The namespace you apear to be using is SOAP NOTE 1.1; it might turn out your service wants to talk SOAP 1.2 instead (which has another namespace and a difference in formatting faults etc).